# Passing value between controllers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, controller

As stated in the title, I'm trying to pass a value (ID) from one controller (**PerksApprovalController**) going to another controller (**PerksDetailsController**). Please find below image for visual reference.

[image: PerksApprovalController]

What I want to do is, when I click the "**Show Details**" button, it will redirect me to another page to display the details of the **Control Number** that I pass.

Below is my implementation.

**Show Details Button Code**

```
<button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="vm.showDetails(p.ControlNumber)">Show Details</button>
```

**PerksApprovalCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

PerksApprovalController.$inject = ['$window', 'app.perksService', 'app.sharedValuesFactory'];
app.controller('app.perksApprovalController', PerksApprovalController);

function PerksApprovalController($window, PerksService, SharedValuesFactory) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;

    vm.showDetails = function (controlNo) {
        SharedValuesFactory.setControlNo(controlNo);
        $window.location = '/PerksDetails/PerksView';
    }
}
})();
```

**PerksDetailCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

PerksDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$window', 'app.perksService', 'app.sharedValuesFactory'];
app.controller('app.perksDetailController', PerksDetailController);

function PerksDetailController($scope, $http, $q, $window, PerksService, SharedValuesFactory) {
    var vm = this;

    PerksService.getPerksItems(SharedValuesFactory.getControlNo()).then(function (response) {
        vm.perksItemDetails = response.data;
    });
}
})();
```

I have created a service just like what they suggested in some topics here.

**sharedValuesFactory.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

// SharedValuesFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
app.factory('app.sharedValuesFactory', SharedValuesFactory);

function SharedValuesFactory() {
    var controlNoShared;
    return {
        setControlNo: function (c) {
            this.controlNoShared = c;
        },
        getControlNo: function () {
            return this.controlNoShared;
        }
    }
}
})();
```

My problem now is, everytime the details page is loaded, `SharedValuesFactory.getControlNo()` returns `undefined`. Looks like `SharedValuesFactory` is reset after the redirect or page load.

Any idea on how to properly pass a value from one controller to another?

TIA

Comment: define `page` and `redirect`... because it looks like you're attempting to do a spa.. which shouldn't have a `after redirect` or `after page (re)load` in the usual sense.

Comment: if you're looking to persist data.. consider storing them.. session/cookie/localStorage/database.. etc etc

Comment: as far as i can see, your code should have worked, cause unless the whole location is reloaded, the data in the service should persist. Can you replicate this issue on plunker or fiddle perhaps??

Comment: "Any idea on how to properly pass a value from one controller to another" yes.. add both controllers to the same app (add appropriate dependency modules), and then do the standard app.config to handle routers and views.. review 'ui-route' module examples.

Comment: @BrettCaswell
Thanks for the hint. I come up with this approach $window.sessionStorage["controlno"]. My question now is, how's the lifecycle of $window.sessionStorage? When is the value be cleared?

Comment: @SunilLama
Looks like the page is reloaded after $window.location

Comment: till the session ends.. which is dependent on your webserver and browser (session cookies also clear when browser apps closes).. but apparently sessionStorage is scoped a bit differently.. a new tab starts a new session

Comment: @BrettCaswell So what do you suggest? sessionStorage or sessionCookies? Which is better to use?

Comment: sessionCookies are generally just a manner to distinguish a client to the server.. session data is generally in server memory, and isn't accessible to the client.. sessionStorage looks like a good implementation.. but tab scope is a bit limiting

Answer (score 3):

I have a specific way of passing value in between Controllers. Hope it does the trick!

**Note:**
*Not Sure what sharedValuesFactory.js is being used for! Assumming You are using this service to pass Data in between Controllers only. According to me only One service suites your requirement i.e  PerksService.*

The button  passes the value (ID) of "ControlNumber".

```
<button class="btn btn-xs" ng-click="vm.showDetails(p.ControlNumber)">Show Details</button>
```

In PerksApprovalCtrl.js pass the controlNo you are getting on button click to the url of the page as in of a different view

**PerksApprovalCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

PerksApprovalController.$inject = ['$window', 'app.perksService'];
app.controller('app.perksApprovalController', PerksApprovalController);

function PerksApprovalController($window, PerksService) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */
    var vm = this;

    vm.showDetails = function (controlNo) {
        $window.location = ;
        $location.path('/PerksDetails/PerksView'+controlNo);
    }
}
})();
```

In Routes.js or the place where you define the routes of your angular application  add the following lines:

```
.when('/PerksDetails/PerksView/:controlNo', {
    templateUrl: '<YOU DEFINE THE TEMPLATE>',
    controller: 'PerksDetailController',
    reloadOnSearch: false })
```

Here ":controlNo" is used to pass the value you are passing in the url from PerksApprovalController.

In PerksDetailController we get the controlNo from routeParams and pass it to your PerksService to get the details from it.

**PerksDetailCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

PerksDetailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$window', '$routeParams', 'app.perksService'];
app.controller('app.perksDetailController', PerksDetailController);

function PerksDetailController($scope, $http, $q, $window, $routeParams, PerksService) {
    var vm = this;

    PerksService.getPerksItems($routeParams.controlNo).then(function (response) {
        vm.perksItemDetails = response.data;
    });
}
})();
```

Hope it Solves your problem! Thank You!

Comment: This is my last resort. Convert my current setup to routing. I thought passing value from one controller to another controller is just easy. :) Thanks for your answer but I think I'll stick on $window.sessionStorage for a while and monitor the behavior.